# Food Grade Steel Drums

Tags: equipment, boil-kettle, boil-equipment

I'm thinking about buying some a HUGE Blue food grade steel drums, which is either painted or enameled.

If I correctly modify them, will these be okay for FV, Mashing Tubs, Boil Kettle, Strike Boiler?

My concern is they are 205 liters / 45 Gallons

Comment: This reminded me of a post I saw in the Home Brew Talk forum a while back. a guy uses pool filters to do 25 gallon batches... you can see the thread here: http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f51/pool-filter-fermenter-364552/

Comment: Note that those are SS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be concerned about their durability. They are likely not stainless steel under the finish so any exposed metal will rust. If you are planning on drilling holes for spigots, sight glasses, etc., that will definitely be a problem. Also, mash tuns and boils kettles take a beating with exposure to somewhat acidic wort and  harsh cleaners. I assume you are planning a clean-in-place system with kettles that size? How well with the blue paint/enamel stand up to that?

Stainless steel is definitely more expensive, but it will last forever if used and cleaned properly.

Answer (score 2):

I would not count on those being food grade.  I recommend you look into 55 gal. SS barrels.

Comment: If advertised as food grade, am I good to go?

Comment: I would think so.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but they are expensive. Like nearly as expensive as a 55 gal Blichmann kettle. http://morebeer.com/products/blichmann-55-gallon-boilermaker-brew-pot.html?gclid=CIjIt_b-krwCFWHNOgodK04Aww  vs SS drum: https://www.google.com/search?q=55+gallon+stainless+steel+barrel#q=55+gallon+stainless+steel+barrel+drum&safe=off&tbm=shop

Comment: I have local contact that is selling 2 for £20, 2nd hand food grade.